# UIButton background image is not changing in iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have the `boolean` value `checked=NO`, and i change it to `YES` based on the Boolean conditions,
if the condition become yes, then the button image change to checked image, or it will be unchecked image in `UIButton`.

The below code works well in iOS 7.0, but not in iOS 6.1 and iOS 6.0 
How to make this work in iOS 6.1 and iOS 6.0, Thanks in Advance

```
if (checked)
 {

 [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select_check_box"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else{

 [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deselect_check_box"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: show the full method plz

Comment: -(void)checkBtnActionUsing:(UIButton*)sender{
 BOOL checked;if (!chkFlag) {
                chkFlag=YES;
                checked=chkFlag;
                value=@"1";
            }
            else{
                chkFlag=NO;
                checked = chkFlag;
                value=@"0";
            }
if (checked) {
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select_check"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }
    else{
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"new_check_box"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from your question is you want to change the Image of button on the basis of checked value:

You can use setImage:forstate method of UIButton, available in iOS 2.0 and later.

```
if (checked)
{
     [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select_check_box"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else{
     [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deselect_check_box"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Reference: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setImage%3aforState%3a)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (checked) 
{
 [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select_check_box"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
} 
else
{
 [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deselect_check_box"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Am sorry yaar, the code you given is right only, i've done something wrong in my code...now its fine